# modsecurity whitelisting certian types of cookies

Tags: cookies, mod-security

I am seeing cookies being generated on our server which appear to be from 3rd party objects in the site and don't show themselves when one logs in or navigates through the site.

The cookies are random but all start with Wm. So some of them might be wm_cm_12345-12345-12345-12345 and some of them might be wm-wtchd-22. I am thinking that perhaps I could have them not alert if they're Wm*.

How can I whitelist cookies starting with Wm?

and any other ideas that you might have that you'd like to include with how I can whitelist these?

Thanks

an example cookie

```
TX:981243-Detects classic SQL injection probings 2/2-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQLI-REQUEST_COOKIES:wm_rx_123456eabcdef7890_0edb4989-1523-ff12-ccab-beddddaaffccc. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_49_inbound_blocking.conf"] [line "26"] [id "981176"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 41, SQLi=9, XSS=): Last Matched Message: 981243-Detects classic SQL injection probings 2/2"] [data "Last Matched Data: \\x22:61"] [hostname "Somefoowebsite.com"] [uri "/images/nyancat.jpg"]
```

Another example of what I am seeing:

```
[30/Nov/2015:13:54:27 --0700] [bumblebeetune.com/sid#7fee134ee758][rid#7fee13b510d8][/nyancat.foo][2] Warning. Pattern match "(.*)" at TX:981243-Detects classic SQL injection probings 2/2-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQLI-REQUEST_COOKIES:[30/Nov/2015:13:54:27 --0700] [bumblebeetuna.com/sid#7fee134ee758][rid#7fee13b510d8][/nyancat.foo][2] Warning. Pattern match "(.*)" at TX:981243-Detects classic SQL injection probings 2/2-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQLI-REQUEST_COOKIES:wm_ct_877bb6e0e4744fd6a270f70f3e0c8a67_d464ab47-3cf0-fe3f-89d5-bd785f7bdcfa. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_49_inbound_blocking.conf"] [line "26"] [id "981176"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 18, SQLi=4, XSS=): Last Matched Message: 981243-Detects classic SQL injection probings 2/2"] [data "Last Matched Data: \x22:61"]. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/activated_rules/modsecurity_crs_49_inbound_blocking.conf"] [line "26"] [id "981176"] [msg "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 18, SQLi=4, XSS=): Last Matched Message: 981243-Detects classic SQL injection probings 2/2"] [data "Last Matched Data: \x22:61"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want you can add config like this (as detailed [here](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity/wiki/Reference-Manual#SecRuleUpdateTargetById)):

```
SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981243 !REQUEST_COOKIES:'/^wm.*/'
```

In fact this is already built in for some regular cookies that this rule incorrectly flags as false positives (__utm used by Google Analytics and _pk_ref  used by a similar analytics piece of software) as you can see when looking at the [rule definition](https://github.com/SpiderLabs/owasp-modsecurity-crs/blob/master/base_rules/modsecurity_crs_41_sql_injection_attacks.conf) of the original rule that flagged:

> SecRule
>   REQUEST_COOKIES|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/__utm/|!REQUEST_COOKIES:/_pk_ref/|REQUEST_COOKIES_NAMES|ARGS_NAMES|ARGS|XML:/*
>   "(?i:(?:[\"'`´’‘]\s*?\*.+(?:x?or|div|like|between|and|id)\W*?[\"'`´’‘]\d)|(?:\^[\"'`´’‘])|(?:^[\w\s\"'`´’‘-]+(?<=and\s)(?<=or|xor|div|like|between|and\s)(?<=xor\s)(?<=nand\s)(?<=not\s)(?<=\|\|)(?<=\&\&)\w+()|(?:[\"'`´’‘][\s\d]*?[^\w\s]+\W*?\d\W*?.*?[\"'`´’‘\d])|(?:[\"'`´’‘]\s*?[^\w\s?]+\s*?[^\w\s]+\s*?[\"'`´’‘])|(?:[\"'`´’‘]\s*?[^\w\s]+\s*?[\W\d].*?(?:#|--))|(?:[\"'`´’‘].*?*\s*?\d)|(?:[\"'`´’‘]\s*?(x?or|div|like|between|and)\s[^\d]+[\w-]+.*?\d)|(?:[()\*<>%+-][\w-]+[^\w\s]+[\"'`´’‘][^,]))"
>   "phase:2,capture,t:none,t:urlDecodeUni,block,msg:'Detects classic SQL
>   injection probings
>   2/2',id:'981243',tag:'OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQL_INJECTION',logdata:'Matched
>   Data: %{TX.0} found within %{MATCHED_VAR_NAME}:
>   %{MATCHED_VAR}',severity:'2',setvar:'tx.msg=%{rule.id}-%{rule.msg}',setvar:tx.sql_injection_score=+1,setvar:tx.anomaly_score=+%{tx.critical_anomaly_score},setvar:'tx.%{tx.msg}-OWASP_CRS/WEB_ATTACK/SQLI-%{matched_var_name}=%{tx.0}'"

Now if you can figure our that regexpr then you're a better man than me, but you can see the config for which cookies it applies to at the beginning.

Note it's best to add above config to dynamically modify the rule, rather than editing the rule itself since upgrading your rules will overwrite any edits whereas overrides can be kept (assuming they are in a separate override file which is still present after the upgrade).

Comment: hmm I am trying to figure out why this rule didn't work. I am still seeing

Comment: I had the wrong id in my answer (981241 instead of 981243). Corrected now. You also might need to add the above SecRuleUpdateTargetById bit AFTER the rule is defined rather than before (not sure if this is necessary but my config adds amends like this after).

Comment: I noticed that, but I corrected this already. When you say to add after is that to have the rule ID to be after or the .conf to be a higher number?

Comment: Make sure the .conf file defining the rule is loaded before the .conf file that alters the rule.

Comment: Yes, I have that for as conf 15. Is SQLI-REQUEST_COOKIES it's own var or something? I have them all eliminated except for one of those ironically. wm_ct_944bb6e0e3356fd6a990f70f3e9c9c77_84a4567-6b37-d71e-b7db-1d221326c157

Comment: No that's just logging info. You're rule amend must not be being picked up for some reason. Is it the exact same error message?

Comment: this appears to be the original rule that is alerting

Comment: SecRule TX:ANOMALY_SCORE "@gt 0" \
    "chain,phase:2,id:'981176',t:none,deny,log,msg:'Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: %{TX.ANOMALY_SCORE}, SQLi=%{TX.SQL_INJECTION_SCORE}, XSS=%{TX.XSS_SCORE}): Last Matched Message: %{tx.msg}',logdata:'Last Matched Data: %{matched_var}',setvar:tx.inbound_tx_msg=%{tx.msg},setvar:tx.inbound_anomaly_score=%{tx.anomaly_score}"
        SecRule TX:ANOMALY_SCORE "@ge %{tx.inbound_anomaly_score_level}" chain
                SecRule TX:ANOMALY_SCORE_BLOCKING "@streq on" chain
                        SecRule TX:/^\d/ "(.*)"

Comment: That rule fires only if other rules also fire and so the anomaly score is higher than a threshold.

Comment: Thought I would try this to see if it works.SecRuleUpdateTargetById 981176 !REQUEST_COOKIES:'/^wm.*/' "phase:1,t:none,nolog,pass,ctl:ruleRemoveById=981176,setvar:tx.anomaly_score=-5" And it hasn't

Comment: Parameters like phase, nolog, pass and ctl can only be specified in a new rule (using SecRule) not in a SecRuleUodateTargetById statement. Which rule other than 981176 is firing?

Comment: 981243 , 981257 , 981245 are as well

Comment: Then add similar fixes for those rules and that will stop the overall rule 981176 firing.

Comment: I have but still the same results.

Comment: Please post more details in the original question to show ALL the alerts. Can't guess what you're seeing.

Comment: Ok added more info, but so far nothing of what we have done has made any visible impact.

Comment: One thing that sticks out to me is "Inbound Anomaly Score Exceeded (Total Score: 18, SQLi=4, XSS=)" . Is there something that can be done for this in this situation?

Comment: This worked after I set it after all rules on 61 conf loaded in.